# Battle game - how to make infinite missile?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I'm making a BattleCity like game and I want my Tank to keep releasing missile whenever I hit spacebar key. I've used Array but I can't let the index leave blank since I have an integer of number of missiles.

```
PictureBox[] missileArray = new PictureBox[10];
int missileNumber = -1;
PictureBox missile = new PictureBox();
Boolean startshooting = false;   

private void shootingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < missileNumber; i++)
    {
        missileArray[i].Top -= 20;
    }
}

private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(missile);
        missile.Width = 10;
        missile.Height = 10;
        missile.BackColor = Color.Black;
        missile.Top = MainTank.Top + MainTank.Height / 2 - missile.Height / 2;
        missile.Left = MainTank.Left + MainTank.Width / 2 - missile.Width / 2;

        missile.BringToFront();
        missileNumber += 1;
        missileArray[missileNumber] = missile;
        shootingTimer.Start();
    }
```

The missileArray can't leave it blank, it needs to have an array size or something. How will I make it infinite firing missiles?

Sorry that I can't explain it properly and my English is not that good.

Comment: If you want a dynamic size array you can use a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

Comment: Why don't you try with `List<PictureBox>` instead of the Array. Lists doesn't have fixed size

Comment: I've answered your question but there's an unrelated bug in your code: you keep adding the same missile object over and over. You should be instantiating new missiles every time the space bar is pressed. There's no reason to have a `missile` field in your class, it can be scoped to the space bar press event.

Comment: Uhm maybe I didn't really explained my problem, What my problem is that the missile keeps returning back to it's position where my MainTank is whenever I press Spacebar key. How can I make it like when it fire missile it can also fire another missile without returning back to its position?

Comment: @MineDyse: If the question needs fixing, please edit the question instead of commenting on it. People aren't always going to read all the comments before they attempt to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Response to your question**

> I've used Array but I can't let the index leave blank

This scenario, i.e. an undetermined number of elements in a collection, is the exact reason why developers commonly use lists (`List<T>`) over arrays (`T[]`). It's not the only reason, but a big (if not the biggest) reason to use lists.

Reworking your code to using a list (I've omitted all other code)

```
List<PictureBox> missiles = new List<PictureBox>();

private void shootingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var missile in missiles)
    {
        missile.Top -= 20;
    }
}

private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
    {
        missiles.Add(missile);
    }
}
```

While the usage is slightly different, a list behaves exactly like your array would (it even allows for indexed access) but with the added benefit of being able to house any amount of items you put into it.

---

**Response to your comment**

> So in that way it will keep on firing even it doesn't return to its place? Like right now when I pressed Spacebar the picturebox will be sent back

You keep adding the same `missile` object over and over, resetting the existing missile's properties whenever an additional missile should be fired. You should be instantiating new missiles every time the space bar is pressed. There's no reason to have a missile field in your class, it can be scoped to the space bar press event:

```
private void Game_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
    {
        var missile = new PictureBox();

        // set all the new missile's properties like in your code

        missiles.Add(missile);
    }
}
```

You also shouldn't be starting the `shootingTimer` every time the space bar is pressed. The timer should be started *once* and it will then automatically iterate over all the missiles in the list. When the space bar is pressed, you should only need to add a missile to the list and it will automatically be processed.

The source of the issue you're facing comes from a misunderstanding of how reference types work in C#. That's beyond the scope of an answer on StackOverflow, but I do suggest you read up on [reference types versus value types in C#](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3043992/a-deep-dive-value-and-reference-types-in-net.html) (this link is just one of many resources you can find online.

Comment: So in that way it will keep on firing even it doesn't return to its place? Like right now when I pressed Spacebar the picturebox will be sent back to the main picturebox which is modeled as Tank.

Comment: @MineDyse: That is a problem unrelated to the question you asked here (i.e. how to have a growing array). I already commented on that issue in the comment section under your question, but I'll amend this answer's solution to address that issue too.

Comment: works perfectly now, but the thing is that it doesn't have delays. How will it continue the code to where it makes delay of pressing spacebar?

Comment: @MineDyse: Please post new questions as a new question.